# ¿Donde debería colocar el alert en este ciclo Do While para mostrar el mensaje "Contraseña incorrecta"?

Tags: javascript, loops, ciclos

```
let pass = "ED";
let password;
do{
    password = prompt("Introduzca la contraseña");
} while (password != "ED");
```

Comment: Hola José, te sugiero agregar información en el cuerpo de la pregunta, revisar [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías ponerlo, por ejemplo, antes de preguntar por ella si el usuario ha introducido ya alguna:

```js
let pass = "ED";
let password;
do{
    if (password) alert('Contraseña incorrecta');
    password = prompt("Introduzca la contraseña");
} while (password != pass);
```

Comment: En realidad busco que al responder la pregunta por primera vez si es incorrecta se lea el mensaje. Pero tu código funciona aunque no entiendo porque primero pide la contraseña y luego muestra el mensaje ya que el código está escrito al revés.

Comment: Únicamente muestra el mensaje si la variable `password` tiene algún valor. La primera vez que pasa por el bucle `password` está vacío por lo que no muestra el mensaje. Si se mete una contraseña incorrecta y vuelve a iniciarse el bucle entonces sí que lo muestra.

Comment: P e r f e c t o !

Answer (score 1):

Algo que se me ocurre es:

```js
let pass = "ED";
let password;
do{
    password = prompt("Introduzca la contraseña");

    if(password != "ED"){
     alert('Contraseña incorrecta');
    }
} while (password != "ED");
```

Permanecerá en el ciclo siempre que la clave sea incorrecta.